# Generate Xml from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, xml, stored-procedures

Is there any way to generate the xml in mysql using stored procedure.

Comment: You should provide more details to receive much attention (as the time of posting there are only 18 views during 6 days!).

Answer (score 2):

Head to the [post](http://eriksdiary.blogspot.com/2007/07/xml-output-from-mysql.html) of [Erik](http://www.blogger.com/profile/07865795210715993795) entitled **XML output from MySql**.

Quotes:

> Many times you need to produce XML output from your MySql database.
>   MySql has no built-in support for creating XML in it's SQL
>   implementation but you can easily add support using the stored
>   function feature.
>
> To make xml output easier I have made three small stored SQL
>   functions. They produce xml fragments, which you can easily put
>   together to get a complete xml